# Login redirect after redux action triggers firebase signin method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I've been having a hard time trying to redirect to the PrivateRoute that I have for homepage after a user is authenticated via Firebase auth combining it with Redux actions and reducers.
Right now if I history push from the dispatch action it is too early for auth to activate the PrivateRoute and if I redirect from componentDidMount it doesn't redirect to '/' which is homepage. Please let me know the best approach to do this. helpp!

**In my Auth.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./fbConfig";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      setPending(false)
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**In my login.js**

```
class Login extends React.Component {

    state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
      })
    }
    
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.state);
      this.props.signIn(this.state);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.auth.isEmpty != prevProps.auth.isEmpty) {
        // CODE NOT WORKING
        console.log("hey");
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    }

    render() {
     ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    authError: state.authError,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
  return {
    signIn: (creds) => dispatch(signIn(creds, props))
  }
}

const enhance = compose(
  withRouter,
  withStyles(useStyles),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
);

export default enhance(Login);
```

**In my authActions.js**

```
export const signIn = (credentials, props) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
      const firebase = getFirebase();
      
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        credentials.email,
        credentials.password
      ).then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' });
        // this.props.history.push('/');
      }).catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', err });     
      });
    }
  }
```

**PivateRoute.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "./Auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(currentUser);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};


export default PrivateRoute
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
            <div>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                  <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </AuthProvider>

  );
}
```